# Commit files in Vagrant box or out of it

Tags: git, vagrant

Possibly a very stupid question, feel free to flag it if so.

I have a Vagrant box that maps my host computer's `code` folder to its own `code` folder. When I make changes to a project in that folder and want to `git commit` and `push` them, does it make a difference whether I do it from the box (after I've ssh'd into it) or from my host machine?

Comment: no difference as long as you have set your user name and email `git config --global user.email "email@example.com"` and `git config --global user.name "example"`

Comment: It does when you work via ssh (which I would recommend). First, in order for the git authentication to even work - you'll need to sync your ssh keys - and assuming you did that, the difference may potentially be in different git config parameters. Common case: people forgot to set their git config while copying/mapping only ssh to vagrant and the result would be funny anonymous "vagrant" user who made a commit